# Different ways of calling render() in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, render

I am having some difficulty understanding how render() works. I have read posts about the functionality of the function, however still have unanswered questions.

Reading about it in the Django Docs, and looking at the source, it is not a method pertaining to any class. Instead, it is a function just like many others, and one that takes several arguments (request, template_name, etc).

Though, in the [Django Book](http://gsl.mit.edu/media/programs/south-africa-summer-2015/materials/djangobook.pdf), it is stated as a method you can call on a template object. That is, you can instantiate an object, and immediately call the render method on that object with some context. I have previously used it without specifying any template name, merely calling it on a template object with some context, as previously described.

Why do the Docs describe it as a free-standing function, not belonging to a class, when it can be called on a template object like as if it was a method of a template class? Why don't I find a template class anywhere? What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about. There are two different things called render; a standalone function, and a method on the Template class that is called by that function.

Comment: That makes sense. Did not expect that really. Where can I find the Template class? I cannot find a single post about it here on StackOverflow, and have a hard time finding it within the Docs!

Comment: It's rare that you interact directly with `Template` objects, in my experience, but: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/

Comment: I am sure it is! How come it is possible to instantiate like this: a = Template('template-text')? Is there an actual Template class? With a method render? I can see no information on either one of those questions on the website you linked. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: To load from a string...well, you wouldn't. But if for some reason you needed to, you could call the template engine directly to get a `Template` instance as shown here, using `from_string`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.engines

Comment: and then the `render` method is described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render

Answer (score 0):

You asked about template class, what we usually use in Django is class `TemplateView`, where you can provide `template_name`.

It is also worth mentioning, that this book is quite old. It refers to version 0.96 (you can check on page 7), while newest Django version is 2.0. 
There has been a lot of changes since then, so I wouldn't recommend using it with newer versions.

Comment: You're right about the book being old, but there's a big difference between template objects and the `TemplateView` class-based view.

Comment: I have noticed it is quite old, however many of the concepts appear to be more or less the same. My objective with the book is really to just gain a better understanding of the underlying concepts of the framework, and it definitely provides good information on that end. For clarification, are template objects an outdated aspect of the language? I am wholly aware that is not commonly used, but I really just want to learn.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper that's right, I was just surprised (as you) that OP wants to interact directly with `Template` class for some reason, I never did and wasn't sure if OP is aware of standard use of class-based views. But I should have mentioned that.